# BigqueryでGoogle Drive（スプレッドシート）とCSVデータを統合したテーブルを用意する方法

Tags: google-bigquery

BigqueryでGoogle Driveなどの日々更新される外部ソースのデータと、CSVアップロードなどの通常のデータを統合させた1つのテーブルを作る方法はございますでしょうか？

詳細としては、
数年分の顧客データの蓄積と解析をBigqueryで実施しようとしています。BigqueryデータのビジュアライズツールとしてGoogle Datastudioを利用予定です。

Datastudioで過去数年分の顧客データを読み込むには、Bigqueryに単一のテーブルとして顧客データを用意しなければならないはずですが、現状は複数のExcelファイルとして顧客データが保存されており、そのデータが日々更新されている状況です。このデータを週次で分析していきたいと考えており、下記の方法で実現できるのではないかと考えました。

1. 2016年より前のデータはBigqueryにそのままCSVデータとしてインポート（input1）
2. 2017年今年のデータは Google Drive（実際はGoogle sheet）で日々更新しているものを外部ソースデータとしてBigqueryのテーブルとしてインポート（input2）
3. 1と2のテーブルを連結させたビューを作成（output）★
4. Datastudioに3を連携させてビジュアライズ

ただ、この★3の部分でGoogle Driveと連携させているデータでは複数テーブルに対するクエリが動きません。

例えば、2つのテーブルを下記のように、

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
 `hogehoge.hogehoge.input*`
```

と指定しますと、

```
Error: External tables cannot be queried through prefix.
```

といようなエラーが出ます。Google Driveなどの外部ソースのテーブルではワイルドカードが動かないということでしょうか。外部ソースデータをビューに切り替えてもエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix.
```

このような場合にエラーを出さず解決させる方法が何かございますでしょうか？いずれにしても、日々更新されるGoogle DriveのデータをBigqueryに取り込みつつ過去のデータとともに単一のテーブルを作れる方法であれば問題ないです。

Answer (score 1):

Legacy SQLのTABLE_DATE_RANGEでは、federated tableに対してもクエリを実行することができました。
StandardSQLもしばらくしたら対応されるのではないかと思いますが、とりあえず今すぐ実行したいなら、Legacy SQLで書いちゃうのが早そうです。

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(federated.t, TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'),TIMESTAMP('2017-01-02'))
LIMIT
  1000
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。この方法で確かに問題なく動きました。大変助かりました！